# How to calculate the minimum possible flight speed of an aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-performance

So for the minimum possible flight speed an aircraft can fly with for a given altitude, I just use

Lift=Weight  and solve for the velocity.

But: I need to insert a lift coefficient, which I can get from airfoil + body data table.

Lift coefficient depends on the angle of attack. Up to stall, the lift coefficient increases with angle of attack.

I have my highest lift coefficient for an angle of attack of alpha=24°

So my question: does it make sense to choose this lift coefficient?

Because: the higher my angle of attack, the less thrust of my jet engine is there to counterbalance the drag component, so I will have to give more thrust (because only the cos(alpha) component can be used of the thrust vector).

So in the end, I could use my highest angle of attack and reduce flight velocity, as long as I have enough thrust to counterbalance the drag component, is this correct?

If yes, are there any limitations as long as I do not have a stall?

Comment: You seem to have an understanding of the basic variables at play-- I'm trying to figure exactly what the question is--

Comment: Re "so I will have to give more thrust (because only the cos(alpha) component can be used of the thrust vector"-- this is a true statement, but, of course, the cos (alpha) issue which affects the available thrust (measured along the flight path axis) is not the *only* reason that you need more thrust (measured along the engine axis) when you are flying deep on the backside of the thrust-required curve, than when you are flying at the max L/D speed!

Comment: It looks like you have created multiple accounts. Be aware that you won't be able to fully participate to the site if you don't gather enough reputation. It is easier to do so by having one single registered account: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: You are right that cos(alpha) reduces the thrust component counteracting drag (assuming that the thrust line is along the average chord line, which defines angle of attack alpha). But did you also consider that sin(alpha) now acts along the lift direction?